# Format date in DataGridView column in custom format

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview, date-format, sql-update

I have a **DataGridView** where the user inserts data about different products. One of the columns holds data for the date when the item expires. I was told to make it as easy and fast for the user to type this date, so I have to make the date format something like this: **"ddMMyy"** (without point or slash separators between day, month and year, with only 2 digits year). The DataGrid is bound to my **DataBase**, so I guess I should convert the user input to the accepted format of the DataBase ("dd.MM.yyyy") before the update to the DataBase is made.

However, I tryed doing this update in the **CellLeave event**, since it is the first event that gets called when the user leaves the cell. It didn't work, tryed it in the **CellEndEdit**, **CellValidating** and **CellValidate**, still no succes (the update in the DataTable is made in the **CellValidate** event). I tryed the following code, but on a breakpoint it seems I am not formatting the actual text in the DataGrid, but the old value that is already in the database:

```
If dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("Expiry_Date").Index Then
        Dim strData As String = dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value.ToString()
        Dim day As String = strData.Substring(0, 2)
        Dim month As String = strData.Substring(2, 2)
        Dim year As String = strData.Substring(4, 2)
        strData = day & "." & month & "." & year
        Dim d As Date = Date.Parse(strData)
        dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = d
End If
```

The value inserted in the DataGridView cell was "160420", which should have been formatted to "16.04.2020", but the strData showed "20.09.2021", which is the old value, the one that was in the DataBase before the edit.

I know I might miss something that's actually quite easy, but so far I have not managed to work this out. Although the code I provided is VB.NET, any C# help is also appreciated, since I can easily convert between these two.

Comment: Firstly, please tell me that you are not string dates in the database as text.  Assuming that you're not committing such a crime, are you saying that you want the user to be able to enter a date in "ddMMyy" format but you want it displayed in the cell in "dd.MM.yyyy" format when not editing?

Comment: Of couse I do not store dates in string format in the database. They are stored in a date column, with the following format: "dd.MM.yyyy". Yes, that's what I would like to achieve, the date to be formatted and displayed as "dd.MM.yyyy" in the datagridview when the user is not editing the date column, so that I can update it in the database as well in another event that occurs later after the user left the cell. Thank you!

Comment: *"They are stored in a date column, with the following format: "dd.MM.yyyy""*.  That's a contradiction. If they're stored as dates then they can't be stored in that format because that would require they be text. Maybe they are displayed by the database in that format, e.g. Access will do that, but that is not how they are stored.  That means that converting them to a format for the database is a meaningless concept.  You need to have binary `DateTime` values and store those to the database.  That's it, that's all.  Display and strorage are two quite different things.

Comment: More than sure that I did some mistakes when I said that. Yes, the column is datetime and the dates are displayed as dd.MM.yyyy, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```vb
Imports System.Globalization

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim table As New DataTable

        With table.Columns
            .Add("ID", GetType(Integer)).AutoIncrement = True
            .Add("Name", GetType(String))
            .Add("Date", GetType(Date)).AllowDBNull = True
        End With

        With table.Rows
            .Add(1, "Peter", #1/1/2000#)
            .Add(2, "Paul", #6/19/1969#)
            .Add(3, "Peter", Date.Today)
        End With

        DataGridView1.DataSource = table

        'Use the display format by default.
        DataGridView1.Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd.MM.yyyy"
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
        If DataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress.X = 2 Then
            'Display the date in the editing format.
            Dim cellValue = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value
            Dim text = If(cellValue Is DBNull.Value, String.Empty, CDate(cellValue).ToString("ddMMyy"))

            e.Control.Text = text
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValidating
        If e.ColumnIndex = 2 AndAlso
           DataGridView1.EditingControl IsNot Nothing AndAlso
           Not e.FormattedValue.Equals(String.Empty) Then
            Dim value As Date

            'Validate the input using the editing format and the display format.
            e.Cancel = Not Date.TryParseExact(CStr(e.FormattedValue),
                                              {"ddMMyy", "dd.MM.yyyy"},
                                              Nothing,
                                              DateTimeStyles.None,
                                              value)

            If Not e.Cancel Then
                'Ensure data is displayed using the display format.
                DataGridView1.EditingControl.Text = value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

When an editing session begins, the text in the editing control is explicitly formatted as "ddMMyy" and, if the input passes validation, the text is converted back to "dd.MM.yyyy" format so that the grid will automatically parse it back to a `Date`.

Comment: Thank you vey much, sir, such a genious way of doing this! Saved my day, will upvote and mark as answer. Have a nice day! (:

Answer (score 1):

use CellFormatting event handler

```
private void DataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender,
    DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
    if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Columnname" &&
        e.RowIndex >= 0 &&
        dgv["Columnname", e.RowIndex].Value is int)
    {
        switch ((int)dgv["TargetColumnName", e.RowIndex].Value)
        {

                //Create custom display text/value here and assign to e.Value
                string dataformatValue = //Create from database value;
                e.Value = dataformatValue ;
                e.FormattingApplied = true;

        }
    }
}
```

You just need to create custom display value and let the grid that custom formatting is applied or not.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help me. What I want to achieve is to format the user input, which will be a 6-digits date (ddMMyy, "160420" for instance, that will be formatted and displayed in the dgv cell as "16.04.2020" when the user leaves the cell).